# JQuery / Javascript - Set multiple drop lists to match master drop list on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the header of my web-page I have a drop list. The user can set a value here and then click "Set All".

```
<th>
    <span ="MASTERAVAIL" >
        <select  id="CATAVAIL"  class="myselect  form-control"  name="CATAVAIL" >
            <option  selected value="">Select a value</option>
            <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
            <option value="MTO">MTO</option>
            <option value="Express">Express</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <a class="SetAvail" href="javascript:void(0);">Set All</a>
</th>
```

After clicking "Set All" all instances of the below should be set to match the above choice.

```
<td class="one td_left" nowrap="nowrap">
    <span ="CATAVAIL" >
        <select  id="CATAVAIL"  class="myselect  form-control"  name="CATAVAIL" >
            <option  selected value="">Select a value</option>
            <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
            <option value="MTO">MTO</option>
            <option value="Express">Express</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</td>
```

How can I achieve this? I have a bit of code that works when I use input boxes... but not drop lists... here is that bit of code. It relates to other input boxes but it works on them. I just can't adapt it for drop lists.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $=jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myInput = $('#MASTERDATE4');
         $('.SetDate4').click(function() {
               $('input.CATDISCSTART').val(myInput.val());
         });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using many class names wrong, interchanging them with id. What is this  `<span ="CATAVAIL" >`? and multiple elements were also having same id which you should not do and set the value of the input on change of select not on `document.ready()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myInput;
  $('#CATAVAIL').change(function() {
    myInput = $(this).val();

  });

  $('.SetAvail').click(function() {
    console.log(myInput)
    $('#CATAVAIL2').val(myInput);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<th>
  <span>
<select  id="CATAVAIL"  class="myselect  form-control"  name="CATAVAIL" >
<option  selected value="">Select a value</option>
<option value="Standard">Standard</option>
<option value="MTO">MTO</option>
<option value="Express">Express</option>
</select>
</span>
  <a class="SetAvail" href="javascript:void(0);">Set All</a>
</th>
<td class="one td_left" nowrap="nowrap">
  <span>
<select  id="CATAVAIL2"  class="myselect  form-control"  name="CATAVAIL" >
<option  selected value="">Select a value</option>
<option value="Standard">Standard</option>
<option value="MTO">MTO</option>
<option value="Express">Express</option>
</select>
</span>
</td>
```